# Salesforce Connect Apex Connector Framework Deployment Error

Tags: integration, metadata-api, lightning-connect, salesforce-connect

I am getting the following error on my external objects after deploying them using the Force.com ANT Migration Tool.

**MISSING LABEL** PropertyFile - val DataSourceDataTypeNotSupported not found in section ApexConnectorErrors

This error appears in the related list where the External Object is the related list. This only appears to happening on either Currency Fields and Date Fields.

If I delete the Currency and Date fields on the deployed external object, and recreate them declaritively the error goes away.
There appears to be an issue with the deployment using the ant migration tool and the metadata.

Can anyone help with this issue.